# Shutdown from terminal without entering password?

Tags: command-line, shutdown, sudo

I have desktop edition of Ubuntu.

I like the Terminal so that that I prefer to shutdown my computer with the `shutdown` command.

However when I type `shutdown now` it prompts me to enter my password.Is there any way I can shutdown my computer using this command without entering my password?

Comment: Does anyone know what command is executed when I click "shutdown" in Desktop Environment?

Comment: For me both `poweroff` and `shutdown now`  works from terminal. In Ubuntu 20,04, but I an sure that it has been like that for years.

Comment: Note that there is a difference to whether you have a password and just dont want to type it, or if you have no access to superuser privileges. For the first case, there are many useful answers, but for the latter one, only *Ubuntu 14.10 and earlier* are [helped by this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/385316/830570) and if you have *access to gnome*, you can consider [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/714940/830570). I didn't find a solution for my scenario.

Answer (score 75):

Open up a terminal (CTRL + T)
and type the following  `sudo visudo`

Add the following line:

```
%group_name ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/poweroff, /sbin/reboot, /sbin/shutdown
```

or

```
user_name ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/poweroff, /sbin/reboot, /sbin/shutdown
```

This allows the user/group to run the above three commands, **using sudo**, however with no password.

So, `sudo poweroff` will now result in a passwordless shutdown.

---

However, to make this even cleaner, we'll add an alias, so that running `shutdown` calls `sudo shutdown now`.

Open `~/.bash_aliases` for editing.

```
nano ~/.bash_aliases
```

Insert the following line at the end of the file:

```
alias shutdown='sudo shutdown now'
```

Finally, load the changes to the `.bash_aliases` file...

```
source ~/.bash_aliases
```

Try it out!

```
shutdown
```

*<sub>Thanks, [Eric](https://askubuntu.com/users/65926/eric-carvalho).</sub>*

Answer (score 38):

A safe way to do this **without using sudo** and without tinkering with the system, is by executing these **one-liner** commands:

### For Ubuntu 15.04 and later:

(This is due to Ubuntu's shift in using `systemd` instead of `Upstart`)

```
systemctl poweroff

systemctl reboot

systemctl suspend

systemctl hibernate

systemctl hybrid-sleep
```

Since **hibernate** is normally disabled by default in Ubuntu systems, you can enable this by checking [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/617254/101985). [Original source here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=127962).

### For Ubuntu 14.10 or earlier:

Shutdown:

```
/usr/bin/dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit" /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop
```

Restart:

```
/usr/bin/dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit" /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Restart
```

[consolekit [image: Install consolekit]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/consolekit) should of course be installed your system.

**Other commands you may like:**

Suspend:

```
/usr/bin/dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend
```

Hibernate: (if enabled on your system)

```
/usr/bin/dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Hibernate
```

Comment: This is a useful reference, however the `systemctl` command requires to input the user's password, so it is not applicable as a direct answer to the question.

Comment: Revisited this after more that 8 years. :-) And saw the comment above. I tried the `systemctl` commands on a freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04 system and it did not require `sudo` to execute them.

Answer (score 2):

unity uses many gnome services, and in that case too - you can shutdown gnome way.

```
gnome-session-quit --power-off --force --no-prompt
```

will do the job.

Comment: Looks like this only works for logout. From man page of `--no-prompt`: `End the session without user interaction. This only  works  with --logout.`

Answer (score 1):

While you *can* use the method of allowing `NOPASSWD` on `/usr/sbin/shutdown`, although another, DE-independent solution is to just use `init 0`.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I created a `polkit` file with

```
echo "[Shutdown or suspend without a password]
Identity=unix-user:$USER
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.set-wall-message;org.freedesktop.login1.halt;org.freedesktop.login1.suspend
ResultAny=yes
" | sudo tee /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/allow_shutdown_suspend.pkla
```

With this, `systemctl halt` and `systemctl suspend` work without a password. This also work remotely with e.g. `ssh 192.168.0.55 -t 'systemctl suspend'`.

Answer (score -1):

that is easy.
using -S option like this:

```
echo <your-password> | sudo -S poweroff
```

Comment: Warning: that is very bad practice, as everybody and every process could read `<your-password>` from the history!