# Schedule shutdown

Tags: 13.04

I found the **command ( shutdown -h 02:00  )** to schedule shutdown my machine but want to know that Is it compulsory that user must have logged in with **root login**? Or this command would works for all user?

Comment: this thread has the answer: 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/168879/shutdown-from-terminal-without-entering-password

Comment: you can download ComplexShutDown from software center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with using **sudo** command as following.

```
sudo shutdown -h 02:00
```

surely shutdown command can't works for all user.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `shutdown` command needs root privileges. Same case with `reboot` command.