# shutdown command for GNOME

Tags: 15.04, ubuntu-gnome

I use the icon in the upper right corner of GNOME Shell to shut down my system.

Which command is used to shutdown the system?

- `halt`
- `shutdown -h now`
- Something completely different?

[image]

Comment: which version - gnome 3.16? You may get an idea of which bit to look at from the code of [this extension](https://github.com/arelange/gnome-shell-extension-hibernate-status/blob/master/extension.js) (which works on 3.14 and earlier...)

Comment: EDIT: [much better extension](https://github.com/laserb/gnome-shell-extension-suspend-button) to examine, as it can replace the shutdown button (albeit with a suspend button) - gnome probably uses a backend, or system call (or something...) to tell the system to shutdown - extensions can to some extent execute commands, though privileged shutdown ones may cause issues. What problems if any make you need to do this?

Comment: @Wilf I do not want to install an extension. I want to intervene in the existing system.

Comment: OK (sorry, thought replacing the button was easiest :). Problem is it may make some system call to a backend or something - you could search through the [source](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-shell/tree/?h=gnome-3-16) to see what it does, but I can't see anything obvious. Or you could remove the permission to allow users, apps etc to shut the system down - probably similar to the reverse of [enabling hibernation](http://askubuntu.com/a/617254/178596)

Comment: I think that the command used is a message to `dbus`. The problem is that it changes with gnome versions and underneath system and so on. Maybe http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1660987 can help.  You can use http://vidner.net/martin/software/dbus-spy/ to see what's happening...

Comment: @Rmano This is an interesting approach.

Comment: Use this command "gnome-session-save --shutdown-dialog"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### The command used to shutdown is:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.PowerOff" boolean:true
```

For understanding

`man systemd-logind`

```
systemd-logind is a system service that manages user logins. It is
       responsible for:

       ·   Keeping track of users and sessions, their processes and their idle
           state

       ·   Providing PolicyKit-based access for users to operations such as
           system shutdown or sleep

       ·   Implementing a shutdown/sleep inhibition logic for applications

       ·   Handling of power/sleep hardware keys

       ·   Multi-seat management

       ·   Session switch management

       ·   Device access management for users

       ·   Automatic spawning of text logins (gettys) on virtual console
           activation and user runtime directory management
```

Now read to the systemd/logind wiki http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind/

Comment: It's possible to change this command?

Comment: @A.B. :Why need to change?

Comment: @ErkinAlpGüney Just for fun =)