# RDP power buttons don't work

Tags: server, 20.04, remote-desktop, xrdp

With a clean Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server running GNOME, everything is working fine when I physically log into the unit. But when I RDP into it as xfce4, the *Restart*, *Shu Down*, and *Suspend* button are all greyed out! The only button that is available is *Log Out*.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

How can this be fixed so I can shutdown, suspend, or reboot via Remote Desktop?

Comment: That user may not have permission to shutdown / restart the system.

Comment: How/Where do I go to change this permission?

Comment: I am not sure. Maybe by giving some `sudo` privileges or through `polkit`. This old question may help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/636973/