# enable hibernate on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, hibernate

how to enable hibernate on ubuntu 15.04 ?

NOTE: I tried `sudo pm-hibernate` but when it resumed my computer all the open applications were closed

My RAM size is 4GB, swap size is 6GB

output of `sudo blkid; cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="0B4A-F405" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition"  PARTUUID="d44a3ad4-3dad-4450-8863-a551d3404047"
/dev/sda2: UUID="b5a0202a-34dd-4fc9-8fb9-360169c27808" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="adcf8d36-61f2-4f11-91c0-84272ddc127c"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="swap" UUID="de8544b3-7bca-4ff1-9a1c-755bcc6da7b4" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="6503d611-8305-4511-be08-680e8cf7fe94"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="backup" UUID="fd9554a9-0120-483a-9f71-44890d59bb1a" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="4535eae7-5494-49b7-a720-9e33dd9cd734"
/dev/sda5: LABEL="volume1" UUID="bb69c64d-5c45-4bab-90e1-ba46e5afd6b2" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="094b7241-4895-4051-90ab-439252b4e3f4"
/dev/sda6: LABEL="volume2" UUID="78e88fe7-4eb5-45a3-9673-e14340891d38"     TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="2c503384-ae96-484f-ac54-2265b55ea315"
/dev/sda7: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="1e4e3d03-6720-4ce3-afca-0cec0ece7eb9"
/dev/sda8: UUID="3824EEFE24EEBDCE" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="d25007f0-f962-4cdc-8e67-b54888d3f63b"
RESUME=UUID=8d53d44b-e0da-4599-832f-824884a65bae
```

Comment: Do you have a swap partition? What is its size? What is your RAM size?

Comment: If your swap size is greater that your RAM size, give output of `sudo blkid; cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`

Comment: @Pilot6 updated

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in not matching UUID. You probably re-created your swap partition after install. You can fix it by running

```
sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume <<< "RESUME=UUID=de8544b3-7bca-4ff1-9a1c-755bcc6da7b4"
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

and reboot.

To enable hibernation in shutdown menu you can use [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/617254/167850).

Comment: yes I did recreated swap partition after install, thanks

Comment: hey but how do i get the hibernate button  in panel? in panel i have suspend, restart, shutdown buttons

Comment: This is another issue. First try if it works by `pm-hibernate`.

Comment: no, it didnt work

Comment: @edwardtorvalds Sry. Forgot to add a command.

Comment: Aren't Ubuntu supposed to use systemd now? Or is this part of the stuff they haven't ported yet?

Comment: I did not try it yet. Maybe systemd command should be used.